# Azure CLI - Setting Incoming Client Certificates to Allowed for a Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I'm trying to use the Azure CLI to update the Incoming Client Certificate option under Web App > Configuration > General Settings > Incoming Client Certificates to use the value Allow.

Currently I can only set the value to true/false which correlates to Require/Ignore.

*az webapp update --set clientCertEnabled=true--name MyWebApp --resource-group MyRsGrp*

I haven't been able to find anything in the reference documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_update

Does anyone have a nifty way to configure this setting? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set it to `Allow`, there are two properties need to be set, `clientCertEnabled` and `clientCertMode`, `clientCertMode` is not available in command `az webapp update`, you need to use [`az resource update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az_resource_update).

Just use the command below, it works for me.

```
az resource update --name <webapp-name> --resource-group <group-name> --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type sites --set properties.clientCertEnabled=true properties.clientCertMode=Optional
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tested this solution and it works perfectly. Thanks!